# MongoDB $sortbycount workaround on Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Unfortunately $sortbycount within an aggregate pipeline is currently not support on Microsoft Azure implementation of MongoDB (CosmosDB). How can I model an easy $sortbycount without actually using it but getting the same results ?

```
db.gcfblikes.aggregate(
    ...here are some statements then
    {$sortByCount: "$likes.name"}
    ...more statements
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this aggregation pipeline, `$sortByCount` is simplified form of `$group` and `$sort` by count in descending order

```
db.gcfblikes.aggregate(
    [
        {$group : {_id : "$likes.name", count : {$sum : 1}}},
        {$sort : {count : -1}}
    ]
)
```